# Create IOS 3D effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

How would you go about implementing this kind of 3D effect:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1i2JnJWdCeM

Comment: Be more specific about where you are having trouble, or prepare for the wrath of SO.

Comment: I have no idea where to start? Just a pointer in the right direction would be awesome

Answer (score 2):

I would look into CMMotionManager class to get the devices attitude (pitch, roll, yaw) and then move the background image accordingly..

And for the vague formulation, thats all you get! :P

Good luck
-V

Comment: Id also read up on how perspective is used to make things appear in the distance.